# If Push Notifications aren't 100% of the times delivered, can we use VOIP Notifications?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, voip, aws-pinpoint

Does Push Notification with VOIP playload 100% deliverable? If not, what is the efficient way of triggering an iOS or Android app from a server which is 100% efficient.
Can I use AWS Pinpoint and send a VOIP voice note trigger?

Comment: Push notifications can be delayed because the phone does not keep the connection all the time active to save battery.

Comment: Yes, I got that. What's the solution for this?